# How to add session and cookies for login app?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have done the following app using Node js,mongo db and angular js ,
How to add sesssion and cookie for profile page to be visible only on logged in?

I have the program in github
https://github.com/dhanyamj/loginapp.git

Answer (score 1):

For Client-Side sessions you can use `$cookies` service of Angularjs to manage cookies.

[More info here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

You can also manage `Localstorage` and `Sessionstorage` in Angularjs using this library

[ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

Remember this is only for client side sessions, you also have to create server-side sessions in Node.

Answer (score 0):

Do following

1. On login route return session in login success response (nodejs)
2. When you got success in login controller then set session to cookie or create authService to save session.
3. Send that session value to each authorized api send in headers
4. On private route you have to add resolve and check if it is valid i.e is authorized or not other wise redirect to login page.

Hope this will give you an idea to authorize.

Answer (score 0):

You can use node [passport js](http://passportjs.org/) Local strategy for your authentication middleware. Then do this

```
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {

       // CHECK IF LOGIN
        if (req.user.authenticated)
            return next();

        // IF A USER ISN'T LOGGED IN, THEN REDIRECT THEM SOMEWHERE
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
```

Then in your route pass the function

```
route.get('/profile', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
        res.render('profile');
    });
```

If the user is login it views the profile while if not they will be redirected to your login page.

Comment: I want to use cookies and session @jsaon Llamorin